# How can I create an encrypted file on OSX for opening on Win7 w/out 3rd party software?

Tags: encryption, windows, disk-encryption, macos

I do love PGP/GPG, but I have users who don't want to, or can't, install 3rd party binaries. Is there a way on OSX to create a (strongly) encrypted file on OSX which can be opened by Windows 7?

With OS X's Disk Utility, even when creating an encrypted disk image formated for FAT or ExFAT, the result is a .dmg file that Windows 7 does not recognize.

In the OS X Terminal, you can use "zip -e" or zipcloak, but they use weak encryption. OpenSSL is installed by default, but using it is fairly complex, and I don't know if Windows 7 would know what to do with any of the output formats anyway.

Anyone know how to do this w/out extra software?

Comment: Is using Truecrypt in Portable Mode at the destination a viable option? (http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable)

Comment: While this question is about security features in an OS, it's not actually a security question as much as it is a software usage question. It would be more properly on-topic for [su]. I've flagged this question for migration. If a moderator (or 4 other high-rep users) agree, it will be moved - please don't cross-post.